# Bounce Rate dropped to 2%. Is it due to using both Google Analytics Universal and Async codes together?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

For our website we have both versions of Google Analytics tracking code running.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];

_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
(function(b){(function(a){"__CF"in b&&"DJS"in b.__CF?b.__CF.DJS.push(a):"addEventListener"in b?b.addEventListener("load",a,!1):b.attachEvent("onload",a)})(function(){"FB"in b&&"Event"in FB&&"subscribe"in FB.Event&&(FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","like",a])}),FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","unlike",a])}),FB.Event.subscribe("message.send",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","send",a])}));"twttr"in b&&"events"in twttr&&"bind"in twttr.events&&twttr.events.bind("tweet",function(a){if(a){var b;if(a.target&&a.target.nodeName=="IFRAME")a:{if(a=a.target.src){a=a.split("#")[0].match(/[^?=&]+=([^&]*)?/g);b=0;for(var c;c=a[b];++b)if(c.indexOf("url")===0){b=unescape(c.split("=")[1]);break a}}b=void 0}_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","twitter","tweet",b])}})})})(window);
/* ]]> */
```

and

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {

    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {

        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)

    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),

    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)

    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-2504256-3', 'healthproductsforyou.com');

    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

We also have Cloudfare, LivePerson Monitor and Listrak Analytics.

The problem with bounce rate started after using new version (Universal) tracking code.

Is there any way to get back the real bounce rate without loosing any data ?

Which set of codes should be removed?

Comment: This looks more like a question for [webmasters.se] than a question for a programming site.

Answer (score 0):

If they are being sent to the same UA code, then yes they will clash, giving two pageviews for each real view, and so making your bounce rate effectively 0%.

If you want to get the real bounce rate back, you can half the number of sessions to account for the double hits, and then divide that by the number of bounces.  You can get these metrics in a custom report.

```
bounce rate = number of bounces / number of sessions
```

I would remove the older tracking code going forward.